# When c# Invoke() occurs, I get an Argument exception

Tags: c#, invoke

I have 2 Threads: UI and Server. If the server-thread gets some messages, it has to give it up to UI. That's why I use invoke-method.

```
 public class Server
    { 
    private Form1 myForm;
    private String server;

  public Client(Form1 myForm1, String serv)
  {
    myForm = myForm1;
    server = serv;
   }
   delegate void SetTextCallback(string text, Int16 position);
   public void connection()
   {....
     try
      {
       //Connection succeed
       //got message
       SetText(data[0], Convert.ToInt16(data[1]));
       ...
       }catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
               ....
            }
    }
    private void SetText(string text, int position)
    {
     if (myForm.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(
                                        this.myForm.SetTextToListBox1);
                    myForm.Invoke(d, new object[] { text, position });
                }
    }
```

On the UI side I have this

```
public void SetTextToListBox1(String text, Int16 position){}
```

When I debug I can see that in `setText()` I get an ArgumentException.

Comment: is there a reason you are not using a backgroundworker? Please also expand on the ArgumentException, is there a message and what is in the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If the code pasted is correct and complete you must change `this.myForm.SetTextToListBox1` to `this.myForm.SetText`

Comment: I have a project for smartdevice, that's why i can't use backgroundworker.

Comment: catch (ArgumentException ae)
    {
        actInfo += "ArgumentNullException: {0}" + ae;
    } 
//actInfo is a string that contains all the server-Logs

Comment: Igf you get an ArgumentNullException then: a) myForm is null. b) text is null. Probably a)